# How do you embed iFrame content into a CartoDB infoWindow?

Tags: carto, youtube

All,

I'm trying to embed Youtube videos and SoundCloud audio clips into a CartoDB infoWindow. I'm trying to do this by simply using the {{embed}} column and entering it into the custom infoWindow html...

```
<div class="cartodb-popup">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
      <h4>name</h4>
      <p>{{name}}</p>
      <h4>description</h4>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
                {{embed}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

To see the result, click one of the two point features in the map:

**Result Map:**

http://cdb.io/K8yZ9V

**SoundCloud embed code:**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/74986952&amp;color=ff5500"></iframe>
```

**Youtube embed code:**

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VlmgW9t3dxg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: have a look at your url for the YouTube video.  You're missing the `http` at the beginning.  And your soundcloud url looks weird too.

Comment: @Fezter both were copy and pastes from their respective share/embed options. Youtube missing 'http:' still behaves that way in my browser! Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem, but thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it worked in my browser too.  Just a thought, anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that @Javier provided in January was totally correct at that time, but now due to security restrictions inserting iframes inside the CartoDB Editor (infowindows or legends) is no longer supported.

In order to achieve it, you'd need to use CartoDB.js to create your customs infowindows. Besides this, [make sure you disable "sanitizeTemplate" so that your scripts are not removed](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/api-methods/#sublayerinfowindow).

```
sanitizeTemplate: By default all templates are sanitized from unsafe tags/attrs 
(e.g. <script>), set this to false to skip sanitization, or a function to provide
your own sanitization (e.g. function(inputHtml) { return inputHtml })).
```

Comment: Please can you add more information, I cannot understand how to get a video to embed from this. What do I need to put as code in the Custom HTML section to make it display?

Comment: In the CartoDB Editor there's no way to embed a video/iframe. You would need to write a small HTML + CartoDB.js application in which you can set the sanitize function to false. There's an example here: http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/d5524a6513fee65e3065

Answer (score 4):

From the [mustache documentation](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html):

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return
>   unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.

So in your code, you'll need to write:

```
{{{embed}}}
```

My recommendation, however, is storing the URL in a row and writing the iframe tag in the template:

```
<div class="cartodb-popup">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
      <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
        <h4>name</h4>
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <h4>description</h4>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
           <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="{{url}}"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Javier! ... the SoundCloud worked, but the Youtube doesn't show up. Going to dig into this more today...

Comment: I actually just yesterday was experimenting with youtube, got an example working at https://cholmes.cartodb.com/viz/cecd413c-7eff-11e3-ae96-5404a6a69006/map Was pretty simple:            `<div class="cartodb-popup dark">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
<iframe width="260" height="215" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/QK8mJJJvaes" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>`

Comment: Thanks @cholmes ... I notice your URL doesn't have HTTP: in it either... weird, eh? Have you tried the {{{embed}}} or {{url}} as noted above?

Comment: Huh, that is weird. I just grabbed straight from youtube. And I haven't tried embed or url, don't have any data set up well for that at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

`<script>
     sublayer.infowindow.set({
       template: $('#infowindow_template').html(),
       sanitizeTemplate:false,
       width: 218,
       maxHeight: 100
     });
</script>
    <div class="cartodb-popup v2">
    <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
      <h4>description</h4>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
      <h4>sound_url</h4>
      <p><audio controls><src="{{sound_url}}" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>`