# Can I upload a video file to embed in a custom infowindow in Cartodb?

Tags: carto, youtube

I want to embed video clips into custom infowindows in Cartodb, and I know how to do this via a youtube link, but is there a way I can embed a video from a file I have saved on my computer? Or does the video need to come from a website?

Comment: Please do a search on the the top right for GIS SE http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83316/how-do-you-embed-iframe-content-into-a-cartodb-infowindow

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate. The other question is how to do an online one, this is 'is it possible to embed video from a file not online?'. The answer is no, since CartoDB is an online platform it needs to access video online. So you have to upload your video to some online video platform.