# Can I add sounds to cartoDB map?

Tags: carto

I want to create an interactive map that includes sound snippets.  Can I do that in CartoDB?  If not, any recommendations on how I can make that happen?

Comment: I've used soundcloud, but takes some finagling: Check this thread http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83316/how-do-you-embed-iframe-content-into-a-cartodb-infowindow